# How to reference a worksheet when creating a libref?

Tags: sas

I am new to SAS and I am trying to create LibRef using an *.xls file. The Excel file has four worksheets: Sheet1, Sheet2, Sheet3 & Sheet4. How do I tell the libref to reference "Sheet1" only?

```
options validvarname = v7;
libname libxls "path ....xls";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK that isn't possible. You set up the libname as a connection to the Excel file (usually XLSX these days, not XLS) and then you can reference the Sheet as you would a data set.

```
libname libxls excel 'path....xls';

proc means data=libxls.'Sheet1'n;
run;

data myData;
   set libxls.Sheet1;
run;
```

You don't always need the quotes and n, but I think you may with XLS files.